# WooCommerce - Get current cart table (before order is placed)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get the current cart table in woocommerce using the current session (as I need to be able to get the cart before an order is placed (to be used for quoting).

I tried this

```
WC()->cart->get_cart()
```

as well as

```
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
```

but they don't work (debugger shows that then fail calling (in order) these functions:

```
public function __destruct() {} from wp-db.php
public function __destruct() {} from cache.php
function shutdown_action_hook() from load.php
```

Any idea why? what am I doing wrong here?

WooCommerce version is **2.6.7**

Wordpress Version is **4.7.2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the issue was woocommerce not being initialised when my page was called.
When I inspected the cart object, it was null.

I then downloaded a similar plugin and I am currently doing exectly what they are doing to initialize woocommerce before my page load, which is adding these lines:

```
include_once( WC()->plugin_path() . '/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-session.php' );
include_once( WC()->plugin_path() . '/includes/wc-cart-functions.php' );
include_once( WC()->plugin_path() . '/includes/wc-notice-functions.php' );

WC()->session  = new WC_Session_Handler();
WC()->cart     = new WC_Cart();
WC()->customer = new WC_Customer();
```

now woocommerce is initialized, the cart object it's not null and I am able to get the cart with all the products and their details